# Is this an answer to Boolos's Logical Puzzle?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

So a friend gave me this riddle: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hardest_Logic_Puzzle_Ever#Unanswerable_questions_and_exploding_god-heads with the added restriction that you can only ask each god at most one question.

First: Will (second or third) and first answer true to whether or not 1 + 1= 2?

If first is silent, ask second

Second: Will first and third answer true to whether or not 1+1 = 2?

Third: Will first and second answer true to whether or not 1+1 = 2?

If first says anything, ask second

Second: Will (first or third) and second answer true to whether or not 1 + 1= 2?

If second says anything, ask third

Third: Is Second the one who always lies?

If Second is silent, ask third

Third: Will first and second answer true to whether or not 1+1 = 2?

---

First: True
Second: Liar
Third: Random

First: Silent
Second: Silent
Third: Random

Conclude -> First tells truth. Second is a liar. Third is random

---

First: True
Second: Random
Third: Liar

First: Silent
Second: Random
Third: Silent

Conclude -> First tells truth. Second is random. Third is a liar.

---

First: Liar
Second: True
Third: Random

First: Yes
Second: Silent
Third: Random

Conclude -> Second is a truth teller. Suppose Third is a liar. He would then not
be able to say anything but he did making him random. So Third is random
and First is a liar.

---

First: Liar
Second: Random
Third: True

First: Yes
Second: Random
Third: No

Conclude -> By answering anything, first is either a liar or a random. If second was a truth
teller, it would stay silent for that question but because it answered, it must be a liar
or a random leaving third to be a truth teller. Then we can just ask the truth teller
which one is a liar.

---

First: Random
Second: True
Third: Liar

First: Random
Second: Silent
Third: Silent

Conclude -> By answering, First is either a liar or a random. Since Second is silent, second tells
the truth. Then because third is silent, third must be the liar. Therefore,
first is a random.

---

First: Random
Second: Liar
Third: Truth

First: Random
Second: Yes
Third: Yes

Conclude -> By answering, First is either a liar or a random. Since Second says yes,
he is either a liar or a random. Therefore, third is a truth teller so we can just ask him
if second is a liar.